# Is there a metric on $X = (-1,1)$ such that the completion of $X$ is just one additional point?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My thought is that, somehow, the metric should identify the points $-1$ and $1.$ I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: If by completion, you mean one extra point added to make all sequences converge, you can add a point that is both $1$ and $-1$ and you get the circle.

Comment: First, map that open interval to a circle, missing one point.

Comment: Add a point $x$ whose neighborhoods are of the form $(-1,-1+\varepsilon_1)\cup(1-\varepsilon_2,1)\cup\{x\}$. As Joe and Gerry have mentioned, this really just forms a circle. You can extend the usual metric on $(-1,1)$ to be compatible with the addition of this single point.

Comment: @JohnGriffin You can't complete the usual metric with a single point---you'll run into problems with the triangle inequality.  Suppose you add a single point $x$.  Then by choosing $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough, we get $d(-1+\varepsilon, x) + d(x,1-\varepsilon)  = 2\varepsilon < 2(1-\varepsilon) = d(-1+\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Right! And that's not even an issue with completion, but just with extending the metric to the new point. My mistake.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Extending the space to a new point is okay---it just can't be a point with arbitrarily small neighborhoods containing both $-1$ and $1$.  Indeed, we can extend the space to $(-1,1]$ or $[-1,1)$ or even---gasp!---$[-1,1]$ without difficulty.  But to complete $(-1,1)$ w.r.t. the usual metric, we need both endpoints.  But it seems that nearly everyone made that mistake on first read (I'll just pretend that I didn't, because I managed to delete my erroneous comment before anyone noticed (I think)).

Answer (score 2):

The circle, with the metric given by arc length, is a complete metric space.  If we remove a point from the circle, this new space inherits a metric from the circle.  The circle less a point is homeomorphic to the open interval $(-1,1)$, thus we can send the circle to the interval and retain the topology/metric (imagine cutting a bracelet, and laying it straight).  The resulting space will be a metric space with underlying set $(-1,1)$.  This space will not be complete with respect to the metric, but can be completed by adding a single point.

Answer (score 1):

Per the previous answer, the metric can be 
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{(\cos \pi x- \cos \pi y)^2 + (\sin \pi x - \sin \pi y)^2}$$

Another idea is the map bijectively $[-1, 1)$ to $[0, \infty)$ and pull back the metric from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: oh.. but what if $x=-y$ ? Maybe there is a $\max$ somewhere? I think  it would map the segment onto the boundary of a square or something?

Comment: I deleted my comment. I had a picture in mind but I botched the algebra. What I meant was that an equivalent metric to $d$ is $e(x,y)=\min (|x-y|,|x+2-y|).$ Intuitively we identify each $x\in (-1,1)$ with $x^*=\{x+2n:n\in \mathbb Z\}$. And $e(x,y)=\min \{|x'-y'|\; : x'\in x^*\land y'\in y^*\}$.

Comment: @Daniel Wainfleet: Oh nice, so you take  a metric on the quotient space. Great point!